# Dynamically generate a grid of images to fit a predefined area

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dynamic

I need to create a grid of instagram images and fit them in a predefined area. For example: I have a `div` of `600x400px` and 50 square images (there will always be an even number of images). I need to arrange the images in rows and columns to fill as much space of the containing `div` as possible.

You can see a fiddle of what I am trying to achieve [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ys041snx/1/). This is the end result:

[image: grid of images, 5x10]

This is actually quite a good result. Things get a little more out of whack when you change the number of images, to 44 for example.

This is how I am working out the grid rows and columns:

```
//container size:
var width = 600;
var height = 400;
var items = 44;
var rows;
var cols;

var rows = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(items));    

while (items % rows != 0) {
    rows = rows - 1
}

cols = (items / rows);

if (rows > cols) { //make it landscape
    //swap values
    rows = [cols, cols = rows][0];
}
```

The output of this for 44 images for example is 4 rows of 11 columns. The combined height of the 4 rows is 232px, quite a lot less than 400px. So how do I change this to fill more space in the container?

Answer (score 0):

The math's a bit tricky due to wrapping.  An alternative is to build the images  string without any dimensions, then grow them iteratively until they overflow the container.

```
var width = 400,
    height = 300,
    items = 44,
    grid_str = '',
    $grid = $('#grid'),
    i;

function dimensions(x) {
  $('#grid div').css({
    width: x,
    height: x
  });
};

$grid.width(width).height(height);

for(i = 0 ; i < items ; i++) {
  grid_str+= '<div class="col"></div>';
}

$grid.html(grid_str);

for(i = 1 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
  dimensions(i);
  if($grid[0].scrollHeight > $grid.height()) {
    break;
  }
}
dimensions(i-1);
```

In [**this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vny2bto7/), change `width`, `height`, and `items`, and you'll see that the maximum size is always chosen for `div` squares.